# Looking for a radial coordinates description of gear teeth

Tags: function, geometry, coordinates, radial

I don't need a physically accurate function, but something that hints at the involute curves, etc.  I was just using `r = 2 + sin^2`, which gets the idea across, but it looks like - ahem.  Googling around, you can find plenty of information on how to draft a 'correct' gear, but nothing in the way of a bare-bones approximation.

EDIT:  The 'look' that I'm after:  http://www.cartertools.com/involute.html

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: You might get better responses with a picture.  And on a math forum.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pylab import *

nteeth = 30
inner = 10
outer = 12

# these are in teeth-hundredths, but half the actual measurement
bottom_width = 22
top_width = 15

def involute_r(angle):
    '''angle is given in teeth-hundredths'''
    angle = angle % 100
    if angle > 50:
        # symmetry
        angle = 100 - angle

    if angle < bottom_width:
        return inner
    if angle > (50 - top_width):
        return outer
    halfway = (inner + outer) / 2.0
    transition_width = 50 - top_width - bottom_width
    curve = 1.0 - (angle - (50 - top_width))**2 / (transition_width ** 2)
    return   halfway +  curve * (outer - halfway)


fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
theta = np.arange(0, 2*pi, 0.001)
r = [involute_r(t * nteeth * 100 / (2 * pi)) for t in theta]
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_ylim(inner, outer+1)
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `r = 2 + sin(24*theta)^12`? It's sort of hard to know what you want without you being more specific in your question.

Comment: It does look a bit like a gear, but more like the escapement gear on a watch than something to take torque.  It's the bulky, angular shape of teeth that you get with an involute construction that I'm after.  (See the new link, above.)

Comment: This isn't really programming-related, so I'm not going to get into details, but you're probably going to need a piecewise function, which you could probably approximate using a Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though the Wikipedia article on [involute curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute) answers your question. It says:

“In [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates) (r, θ) the involute of a circle has the parametric equation:

r = a sec α

θ = tan α − α

where a is the radius of the circle and α is the parameter.”

If you need this in a form parameterized by θ instead of α, then you're going to need to solve it numerically, as I don't think there's a symbolic solution.  You'll also need to take care, since there are infinitely many solutions for r in terms of θ (because of the way the involute spirals about the circle):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That equation for the involute is correct. You use it relative to the pitch radius. I know you're not going for exact, but in practice, that's not quite the right shape. A good gear design book will walk you through all of the quirky details about things like the radius at the base for stress relief. You can [read old versions online using Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=VkEYAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_v2_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=&f=false), and this isn't something that has really gone out of date. It's really pretty fascinating, and you might find some details there which would help make your shape look authentic.